# Updating a vector through a subvector pointer/view/reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a vector `v` whose size is 10 and defined as
`vector<int> v(10, 1);`

I want to take a segment of `v`, for example

`vector<int> segment_of_v(&v[5], &v[10]);`

Now, I want to update `segment_of_v`

`segment_of_v = 5 * segment_of_v;`

But I want this to be such that the update is also reflected in original vector `v`.

I am trying to do this by making pointer to `segment_of_v` but, I am unable to make this `segment_of_v*` . Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really need `segment_of_v` to be a `vector<int>`? Do you need `segment_of_v` for anything?

Comment: You're looking for some variant of `array_view<int>`. Unfortunately, `array_view` doesn't exist. Yet.

Comment: segment_of_v and v should be same type. I am looking for something like array_view<int> as Kerrek pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make `segment_of_v` a `vector<int>`, because that would create a second, unrelated, `vector`.

You could do `int* segment_of_v = &v[5]`, but this will just get you a plain pointer which cannot be used like a `vector`. And this may be dangerous, because as you manipulate the original `v`, it could be reallocated and this pointer will become invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Why is it so complicated?

You can write simply

```
std::for_each( std::next( v.begin(), 5 ), v.end(), []( int &x ) { x *= 5; } );
```

Or if you want to work with the vector as with array then you can use member function `data`. For example expression

```
v.data() + 5
```

will give the initial pointer of your range.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [*`std::transform`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

```
std::transform( v.begin() + 5, v.end(),        // start, end
                v.begin() + 5 ,                // destination
                []( int x ) { return x * 5; }  // Lambda
               );
```

See [`here`](http://rextester.com/JNRSG5753)

Comment: in my question I have shown one transformation as an example. I want to do lots of arithmetics with segment_of_v. sometime I want to pass this segment_of_v to some function. therefore, I need a systematic definition of segment_of_v.

Comment: @musafir you can always have unary function object passed to a wrapper wrapping this `std::transform`, I also just shown _"one"_ example ;)