# Vectors sharing values

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to find how to create a vector inside a bigger one.
It is not a vector of vectors but a vector whose data are shared inside a bigger vector:

```
vector<char> bigger_v(10);
bigger_v.push_back('h');
bigger_v.push_back('e');
bigger_v.push_back('l');
bigger_v.push_back('l');
bigger_v.push_back('o');

vector<char> smaller_v {'w','o','r','l','d'}; //sharing memory with bigger vector

//some magic..

cout<<bigger_v<<endl; // "helloworld"
```

I don't mind if I have to declare first the bigger vector and reserve space enough to contain the smaller vector. And then declare smaller vector inside the reserved space of the bigger vector.

My target is create a frame (bigger vector) with some fixed size values (header) and some variable size values (smaller vector created from another variable size incoming frame). The smaller vector lets me manipulate incoming data easier.

Comment: Looks like you want a `std::vector`, and then [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)'s into that vector

Comment: In C++20 this concept would be known as a [`view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view) a la [`<ranges>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ranges) library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a vector through a subvector pointer/view/reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045208/updating-a-vector-through-a-subvector-pointer-view-reference)

Comment: So, not append?

Comment: Why not `std::string` `std::string_view`? What is rationale to use`std::vector<char>` ?

Comment: Any attempts to share a `char` will almost certainly cost more than duplicating the `char`

Comment: This answer gaves me the solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27045276/10394975
Thanks Ruzihm.

The smaller vector will never modify the vector. Only read. And while the smalle vector is reading, the biggger vector will not be modified. This condition wouldn't cause any problem with reallocation, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors fundamentally own and manage their contents.  This is what vectors do; they may not share memory in any reasonable way.  (Hacks to do so result in undefined behavior).

`std::span`, however, is a view into memory owned by something else.

```
std::span smaller{ bigger_v.begin()+5, bigger_v.end() };
std::copy_n( "world", 5, smaller.begin() );

std::cout<<'"'<<bigger_v<<"\"\n"; // "helloworld"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any way to have to vectors have the same memory, but I can think of two similar ways to have it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<char> bigger_v(10);
    bigger_v.push_back('h');
    bigger_v.push_back('e');
    bigger_v.push_back('l');
    bigger_v.push_back('l');
    bigger_v.push_back('o');

    vector<char> smaller_v{ 'w','o','r','l','d' }; //sharing memory with bigger vector

    const int sz = bigger_v.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < smaller_v.size(); ++i)
        bigger_v.push_back(move(smaller_v[i]));

    for (int x = 0; x < bigger_v.size(); ++x)
        cout << bigger_v[x]; // "helloworld"
    cout << endl;
}
```

The way above moves the memory from smaller_v to bigger_v, so that smaller_v no longer has any contents, and bigger_v has the memory previously owned by smaller_v.

The second way I can think of, the one closer to your idea, would involve having the vectors contain pointers. That is, both smaller_v and bigger_v would have pointers to the same memory. I won't explain it here, but if you want that, you could try.

Comment: Thank you. Second proposition, thinking on vectors, could give me the solution. It is dangerous because one of them could reallocate, but I'm sure that there is a safe way to do it.
On the first one I would have to move from memory to memory and it is what I'm trying to avoid.